# Rental car mileage overage calculation function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a mileage overage calculation function for a C++ program I am writing. I am having problems getting this function to work properly within the switch statement. What I am trying to achieve (or calculate) is the amount of mileage over the carSize mileage limit * days rented. Each carSize has a different overage/mile calculation rate provided below.

My code so far is:

```
double calcMilesFee(int miles, int days, char carSize)
{
    double milesFee = 0;
    double compactOverageCharge = .05;
    double midSizeOverageCharge = .07;
    double fullSizeOverageCharge = .09;
    int compactDailyMilesLimit = 20;
    int midSizeDailyMilesLimit = 25;
    int fullSizeDailyMilesLimit = 30;

    switch (carSize)
    {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
        {
            while (miles > compactDailyMilesLimit * days)
            {
                milesFee =  (miles * days) / compactDailyMilesLimit;
            }
            if (milesFee > compactDailyMilesLimit)
            {
                milesFee = milesFee * compactOverageCharge;
                cout << "Overage Fee is " << milesFee << endl;
                break;
            }
        }


        case 'm':
        case 'M':
        {
            while (miles > midSizeDailyMilesLimit * days)
            {
                milesFee =  (miles * days) / midSizeDailyMilesLimit;
            }
            if (milesFee > midSizeDailyMilesLimit)
            {
                milesFee = milesFee * midSizeOverageCharge;
                cout << "Overage Fee is " << milesFee << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        case 'f':
        case 'F':
        {
            while (miles > fullSizeDailyMilesLimit * days)
            {
                milesFee =  (miles * days) / fullSizeDailyMilesLimit;
            }
            if (milesFee > fullSizeDailyMilesLimit)
            {
                milesFee = milesFee * fullSizeOverageCharge;
                cout << "Overage Fee is " << milesFee << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return milesFee;
```

}

Comment: What isn't working properly?

Comment: Your need case-level break statements unless your intention is to fall through to the next size vehicle, which I highly doubt is correct. And I would *strongly* suggest using integer math with precision to thousands (i.e. an `int` represents a tenth of a penny) and doing the final value resolution at the end. Floating point is *lousy* for doing currency math.

Comment: Also, it looks like your while loops never terminate.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp they don't.

Comment: Correct, my loops don't terminate properly. That is why I had the break in the wrong location. I don't know what I would add to make these loops terminate properly. Also, after fixing the location of the break statements, the function does not enter the loops as I am expecting them too.

Comment: Look up the functions `toupper` and `tolower`.  Using one of these should reduce your `case` statements by half.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems include:

1. You never break from each switch case label except with the if-conditions.
2. Your while-loops never end. There is nothing in the body of the while-loops that will ever change the conditional.

That said, this problem is considerably simpler than you're making it out to be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double calcMilesFee(int miles, int days, char carSize)
{
    const double compactOverageCharge = .05;
    const double midSizeOverageCharge = .07;
    const double fullSizeOverageCharge = .09;
    const int compactDailyMilesLimit = 20;
    const int midSizeDailyMilesLimit = 25;
    const int fullSizeDailyMilesLimit = 30;
    double overageCharge = 0.0;
    int dailyMilesLimit = 0;
    double milesFee = 0;

    switch (carSize)
    {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            dailyMilesLimit = compactDailyMilesLimit;
            overageCharge = compactOverageCharge;
            break;

        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            dailyMilesLimit = midSizeDailyMilesLimit;
            overageCharge = midSizeOverageCharge;
            break;

        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            dailyMilesLimit = fullSizeDailyMilesLimit;
            overageCharge = fullSizeOverageCharge;
            break;
    }

    milesFee = std::max(0, miles - (days * dailyMilesLimit)) * overageCharge;
    std::cout << "Overage Fee is " << milesFee << std::endl;
    return milesFee;
}
```

As I mentioned in comment, I would advise not using floating-point for currency calculation unless mandatory for your assignment. You can do the final result as a floating point value, but were I writing this i would use integer precision to some hard limit (like 10ths of pennies) and perform the floating point conversion *once*, and *last*.

Comment: This is 100% what I was trying to achieve!!  It seems I am exceedingly good at over complicating my codes. Many  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Every case statement should end with `break`. In your case if any of the inner `if` statement fails there is no break making next case statement to execute which results different behavior.